# Laravel wildcard left side (beginning) of URI

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, routes

The following is well-defined in the Laravel docs:

```
Route::get('/users/{userid?}', $callback);
```

But how do I handle a wildcard on the *left hand* side of a URI?  I want the following routes to all be picked up by one statement:

```
/about-us
/en/about-us
/fr/about-us
```

Something like:

```
Route::get('{language_code?}/about-us', $callback);
```

However this results in an unresolved redirect, at least in the project I'm working on.  In summary, how do I handle and optional left-hand wildcard in Laravel?

Answer (score 2):

**No**, you cannot have an optional parameter followed by the required pattern.

Also it has been an issue on the Github repo and was closed by **Taylor Otwell**

https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/3549

Suggested solutions are:

1) Add the optional parameter at the end.

2) You can have a subdomain for it.

Answer (score 1):

As [Balarj](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4584028/balraj-allam) said *"you cannot have an optional parameter followed by the required pattern"*

## But

we can do something diffrent for example:

```
Route::get('{language_code?}/about-us', function($language_code){
   if(!$language_code) {
      // if the user has not provided the language_code param
     return redirect('/about-us');
   }

  return 'Language is ' . $language_code;

});
```

**then** define the the `default` route

```
Route::get('/about-us', function() {
    return 'about-us page';
});
```